# Is there any way to run the below code faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I ran the below code for about 20k data. Although the code is fine, and I am able to get the output but it's running very slow. It took almost 45 mins to get the output. Can someone please provide the appropriate solution to it?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
def demoji(text): 

    emoji_pattern = re.compile("[" 

                               u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons 
                               u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs 
                               u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols 
                               u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS) 
                               u"\U00002500-\U00002BEF"  # chinese char 
                               u"\U00002702-\U000027B0" 
                               u"\U00002702-\U000027B0" 
                               u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251" 
                               u"\U0001f926-\U0001f937" 
                               u"\U00010000-\U0010ffff" 
                               u"\u2640-\u2642" 
                               u"\u2600-\u2B55" 
                               u"\u200d" 
                               u"\u23cf" 
                               u"\u23e9" 
                               u"\u231a" 
                               u"\ufe0f"  # dingbats 
                               u"\u3030" 
                               "]+", flags=re.UNICODE) 

    return(emoji_pattern.sub(r'', text)) 

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df['Body'])
tweets=df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|/n|/r|w/|\n|w/|Quote::"], value=["",""], regex=True)
tweets[u'Body'] = tweets[u'Body'].astype(str)

tweets[u'Body'] = tweets[u'Body'].apply(lambda x:demoji(x))

weets[u'Body'] = tweets[u'Body'].apply(lambda x:demoji(x))

#Preprocessing del RT @blablabla:
tweets['tweetos'] = '' 

#add tweetos first part
for i in range(len(tweets['Body'])):
    try:
        tweets['tweetos'][i] = tweets['Body'].str.split(' ')[i][0]
    except AttributeError:    
        tweets['tweetos'][i] = 'other'

#Preprocessing tweetos. select tweetos contains 'RT @'
for i in range(len(tweets['Body'])):
    if tweets['tweetos'].str.contains('@')[i]  == False:
        tweets['tweetos'][i] = 'other'# remove URLs, RTs, and twitter handles
for i in range(len(tweets['Body'])):
    tweets['Body'][i] = " ".join([word for word in tweets['Body'][i].split()
                                if 'http' not in word and '@' not in word and '<' not in word])
```

This code is to remove special characters, like /n, Twitter mentions, basically text cleaning

Comment: I maybe completely wrong but you should have a look on threading in python. Maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you work with Pandas and start iterating over dataframe content there's a good chance that your approach is lacking. Try to stick to the native Pandas tools/methods, which are highly optimized! Also, watch out for repetition: In your code you do some stuff over and over again. E.g. *in every iteration* of

- the 1. loop you split `df.Body` (`tweets['tweetos'][i] = tweets['Body'].str.split(' ')[i][0]`), only to pick one item from the resulting frame
- the 2. loop you evaluate a complete column of the frame (`tweets['tweetos'].str.contains('@')`) only to pick one item from the result.

Your code could probably look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
tweets = df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|/n|/r|w/|\n|w/|Quote::"], value=["",""], regex=True)
# Why not tweets = df.replace(r'\\t|\\n|\\r|\t|/n|/r|w/|\n|w/|Quote::', ',') ?

re_emoji = re.compile(...) # As in your code
tweets.Body = tweets.Body.astype(str).str.replace(re_emoji, '') # Is the astype(str) necessary?
body_split = tweets.Body.str.split()
tweets['tweetos'] = body_split.map(lambda l: 'other' if not l else l[0])
tweets.tweetos[~tweets.tweetos.str.contains('@')] = 'other'
re_discard = re.compile(r'http|@|<')
tweets.Body = (body_split.map(lambda l: [w for w in l if not re_discard.search(w)])
                         .str.join(' '))
```

Be aware that I don't have any real insight into the data you're working with - you haven't provided a sample. So there might be bugs in the code I've proposed.